# Javascript weird variable becomes null inside event function

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I witnessed something weird in js. Here's the case study :

```
var openModal = function() {

    ...

    var pgwSlider = $('.initPgwSlider').pgwSlider();

    $('#bootstrap-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        pgwSlider.reload();
    });
    $('#bootstrap-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        pgwSlider.destroy();
        pgwSlider = null;
    });

    $('#bootstrap-modal').model({
        show: true
    });

}
```

This works fine the first time I call `openModal()`.
BUT the second time I try to call `openModal()`... I get `pgwSlider` is null, here :

```
    pgwSlider.reload();
```

This shouldn't happen normally, since the whole function `openModal()` is executed, which means that `pgwSlider` is instantiated once again.

Is this some kind of a memory leak ?

Comment: Is there any other place which you start `pgwSlider` as a global or window variable?

Comment: No, it only exists inside the function

Comment: You're adding an event listener on modal hide to set `pgwSlider` to null. You also add an event listener to reload slider on modal open. When you open the modal, the event listener triggers *independent of `openModal`* and `pgwSlider` is null...

Comment: What does reload do exactly? From the code you've posted every time the modal disappears you set `pgwSlider` to `null` and it's an event so it isn't exactly tethered to openModal

Comment: When the modal disappears `pgwSlider` is set to null. But when the function `openModal` is called again it gets a value, so it's not null.

Comment: @Mehdiway But your event listener is called separately, where `pgwSlider` is null!

Comment: @Mehdiway The second call to `openModal` creates a new closure with its own `pgwSlider`. This is independent of the closure created in the first call to `openModal`. However, the events seem to still be hooked up from the first call, so the first `shown.bs.modal` callback will try to access `pgwSlider` from the first closure, which has already been set to `null` by the first `hidden.bs.modal` function.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde That's a nice comment and it would even be a better answer.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde is there some way around this ?

Comment: Try replacing "var pgwSlider = ..." with "let pgwSlider = ..." this will better scope the variable. "let" was introduced by ES6 and is now widely supported.

Comment: I can't use ES6 in my project, I'll have to stick to ES5 for now...

Comment: @TestCandidate That has no effect here. In this case, both `var` and `let` will be defined within `openModal` and not outside of it. They can both be closed over.

Comment: @Mehdiway in this case try removing the var (yes, it would still be valid js). And instead of "pgwSlider = null" use "delete pgwSlider;"

Comment: For the record, I moved `pgwSlider` to the global scope. It now errors in `pgwSlider.destroy()` when I close the modal the 2nd time... WTF

Comment: I'm not familiar with pgwSlider. However, i don't understand why you are destroying it. Is this really needed? Since ur reloading it on open?

Comment: You're right I don't have to destroy `pgwSlider`, I removed it and the code now works properly. Still the puzzle isn't solved :D

Comment: Well, it could be solved if u try my previous comment (removing var and using delete). But yeah, makes more sense to keep it and not destroying. So who cares :p as long as its working now :)

Comment: I actually tried removing var which is moving the variable to the global scope and delete but it didn't work

Comment: Oh well. Black magic then 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159996/discussion-between-mehdiway-and-testcandidate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that every time you call `openModal` you attach an event listener to `'shown.bs.modal'` and `'hidden.bs.modal'`, so the second time `openModal` run and open again the same modal, it fires 2 times `'shown.bs.modal'`: once for the first attachment, once for the current one; but the first `pgwSlider` is now `null` as declared in the first `'shown.bs.modal'`

You can avoid this in 2 ways:

use `.one` to attach only one time to event 
http://api.jquery.com/one/, so it fires event listener only once

```
$('#bootstrap-modal').one('shown.bs.modal' ...
$('#bootstrap-modal').one('hidden.bs.modal' ...
```

or detach listener on close modal (as the fact that you can have only a modal at time on bootstrap) using `.off` http://api.jquery.com/off/

```
$('#bootstrap-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    pgwSlider.destroy();
    pgwSlider = null;
    $('#bootstrap-modal').off('hidden.bs.modal')
    $('#bootstrap-modal').off('shown.bs.modal')
});
```

About memory leak: it's some kind of memory leak, but you could clean   the forgotten listeners later by

```
$('#bootstrap-modal').off('hidden.bs.modal')
$('#bootstrap-modal').off('shown.bs.modal')
```